# YOLOv8 and Jupyter NoteBook - TypeError: can’t convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, yolov8

I'm trying to deploy YOLOv8 code on Jetson Nano, using a Jupyter Notebook. While running my code I'm getting a Type errors while in cell 94 specifically in (pd.DataFrame(a))

`    89: results = model.predict(frame, show_labels=False, boxes=False, save=True)
90: result = model.predict(frame)

```
 91: a=result[0].boxes.data
 92: boxes = results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy().astype(int)
 93: keypoints_data = results[0].keypoints.data

 94: px=pd.DataFrame(a).astype("float")`
```

Any advice how to fix.

Any advice how to fix.

Comment: I would need more information to answer definitively, but a is likely a Tensor bound to GPU memory, which you are trying to put in a df, which uses numpy. Try this:
px = pd.DataFrame(a.cpu().numpy()).astype(float). Similar to how you did in line 92.

Comment: That worked, thanks Ryan.